# Why the wording "land war" rather than just "war"?

Tags: europe, war

Many media outlets call the Russian-Ukraine war the biggest "land war" in Europe since WW2. Examples:

[*The Economist*](https://www.economist.com/the-world-ahead/2022/11/18/why-a-global-recession-is-inevitable-in-2023) (2022-11-18):

> biggest land war in Europe since 1945

[*Reuters*](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/putin-sending-soviet-tanks-into-hungary-czechoslovakia-was-mistake-2023-09-12/) (2023-09-12):

> the biggest land war in Europe since World War Two

[*Associated Press*](https://apnews.com/article/russia-ukraine-putin-nato-politics-jens-stoltenberg-8a3d2b6946bedf12eadbeef19dab10a3) (2023-02-16):

> the biggest land war in Europe since 1945.

Why do they not just say "war" instead of "land war"?

(Has there been a bigger war in Europe since 1945? Have there been bigger "sea wars" or "air wars"?)

Comment: There may be war in the sea, but also information war, cold war, bombing campaign, etc. I think *land war* is intended to exclude mainly the cold war and the Yugoslavian wars.

Comment: @RogerVadim: Were the Yugoslavian wars bigger "non-land wars"?

Comment: [Yugoslav wars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugoslav_Wars) were rather big in terms of population involved, casualties, war crimes, western involvement. Whether they were bigger on a certain scale than the conflict in Ukraine is hard to say, especially because the latter hasn't finished yet (and some of your statements date back at least a year.) So claiming that Russian-Ukrainian conflict is *biggest* might be wrong, whereas in terms of scale of land action it is definitely the biggest.

Comment: Also, the Yugoslav wars are somewhat difficult to classify. They originated from the breakup of the nation state of Yugoslavia, and were a mixture of civil wars, independence wars, insurgencies, and interventions, that blended into each other. "Land war" usually implies organized, symmetric warfare between two nation's armies.

Comment: No way to prove this, but my suspicion is it having to do with the old saying [Never get involved in a *land war* in Asia](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/104366/meaning-of-never-get-involved-in-a-land-war-in-asia-in-the-princess-bride). That's the context the phrase "land war" is known from, so I'd guess anyone using it to describe a specific war is trying to imply its the messy kind of fruitless high-casualty war one would not want to get involved in.

Comment: What I *don't* think this is, is an attempt to avoid the fact that there was perhaps a bigger "non-land" war since then. I think its fair to say there's been no bigger wars in Europe since WWII, period.

Comment: @DevSolar: Isn't the Ukraine war already "bigger" than the Yugoslav wars in pretty much every metric (deaths, wounded, displaced, geographic area, army sizes, populations of combatant states)? (The only metric I can think of where the Yugoslav wars were "bigger" is duration.) In any case, I doubt the Yugoslav wars were what the above writers were trying to exclude when they used the term "land war".

Comment: @RogerVadim I started writing an answer only to find that you've already written that answer in a comment. Suggest upgrading your first comment into a full answer.

Comment: @Allure In fact, I asked [a similar question a few days into the Ukrainian conflict](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/71257/38304), as similar claims were made already then. I feel that now, a year and a half later, evaluating which conflict is *bigger* according to different criteria requires more expertise than I have. Please feel free to write a detailed answer.

Comment: @T.E.D.: But then, getting involved in a *sea* war in Asia can also be a blunder (e.g., the Russo-Japanese War).  Though, I suppose that land wars have generally been worse for European invaders.  Especially in Afghanistan.

Comment: @dan04 - If we're getting technical, then "sea wars" are by definition on bodies of water, of which "Asia" is not one.

Comment: Possibly to avoid whether the "Cold War" counts as a war?